# Проблема при сохранение сущности с составным ключом @IdClass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-jpa

Весь приведенный ниже код работал без всяких проблем пока в проект не домержили еще одну ветку. После чего он стал возвращать следующюю ошибку

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.Long] to required type [com.konex.servapp.entity.user.User] for property 'user': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:576) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 155 common frames omitted
```

Для проекта используется Spring Boot а именно 1.4.1
Структура данных
[image: Схема данных ДБ]

Сущность

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users_companies")
@IdClass(UsersCompaniesId.class)
public class UsersCompanies extends ObjectMapper implements DomainObject {
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="company_id")
Company company;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="User_id")
User user;

@Column(name="position")
private String position;

@Column(name="registration")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date reg;

getter...setter...equals...hashCode...toString}

Класс ключа 

public class UsersCompaniesId implements DomainObject{
private Company company;
private User user;

public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
getter...setter...equals...hashCode...toString}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UsersCompaniesDao extends JpaRepository<UsersCompanies, 
UsersCompaniesId>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<UsersCompanies>, 
PagingAndSortingRepository<UsersCompanies, UsersCompaniesId>{
   UsersCompanies findByUser(User user);
}
```

Если кто сталкивался с чем подобным помогите разобраться в чем проблема

Comment: Проблема точно в составном ключе? Может просто Вы надеетесь, что `long userId` магическим образом превратится в `User user`? Скорее всего нужно реализовывать `findByUserId`, либо фетчить пользователя предварительно. И да, части составного ключа в объектной модели - именно сущности, не идентификаторы.

Comment: Я как бы писал что все работало? Если нет то пишу все работало до мержа. И проблему мы пока обошли но вот только хотелось бы её решить а не обойти.